# Check support for all devices

Tags: blackberry

I did a simple application in the blackberry OS 5.0.0
Is my app has support for all devices? If not, suggest better way to make my app support for all versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you can do 2 things:

1. Install JDE/Eclipse plugin for every version and compile code looking for errors/warnings
2. Install different simulators and test your application there

And to be sure you get a widest range support, see:
[What minimum BlackBerry OS should I develop for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144384/what-minimum-blackberry-os-should-i-develop-for)
[Developing for multiple versions of BlackBerry OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376786/developing-for-multiple-versions-of-blackberry-os)
[How to define supported BlackBerry OS versions and models for application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023501/how-to-define-supported-blackberry-os-versions-and-models-for-application)